# Why do I get a 1x1 matrix when I multiply a Rx1 vector with a 1xR vector

Tags: matrices

Today in the lecture the prof wrote something similar to:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 &...& 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} b_n & b_{n-1}& b_{n-2} & ... & b_2 & b_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

then some magic later $AB$ becomes 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
&&&...\\
b_n & b_{n-1}& b_{n-2} & ... & b_2 & b_1
\end{bmatrix}

Later I tried to perform this multiplication and I found $A^TB$ I got $b_1$ a 1x1 constant...

How can I reproduce the solution that was given in the lecture using matrix $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magical matrix is in fact $A^TB$.

Note that:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  a  \\
  b  \\
  c 
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x & y & z
 \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
  ax & ay & az  \\
  bx & by & bz  \\
  cx & cy & cz 
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you show me how I can visualize this multiplication? Why do I get something like $0*b_n+0*b_{n-1} ... + 1*b_1$?

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant $A^t$ has $n$ rows and $1$ column, and $B$ has $1$ row and $n$ columns. What you have written in the comment is $BA^t$.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, I can't visualize this. An analog would be take vector V = [0, 1], and a scalar $b$, then b is multiplied to each row of V. Let's instead multiply V by [b, a], in this case I can't really visualize this..

Comment: $[0,1]$ and $[b,a]$ cannot be multiplied. The number of columns of the first matrix must be equal to number of rows of the second matrix. That's why I said $A$ need to be transposed.

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant Did you figure out what you were doing wrong?

Comment: The main consider is that the visualization of this matrix multiplication is different than the matrix multiplication I'm used to. Usually when I picture two matrices being multiplied, the left one is rotated, and some summation. But in this case, it seems that the left matrix is just going through the right matrix and picking up the values, generating a square matrix in the process. I need some time to adjust to this. Is it possible to show this is consistent using some closed form matrix multiplication?

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Matrix_multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

they are both $1$ by $n$
so you can do 
$A^t B, B^t A , AB^t, BA^t$

the transposed vectors are $n$ by $1$ so the dimensions of the products are 
$$
n \times n, n \times n, 1 \times 1, 1 \times 1 
$$